# How can i fix this problem "could not convert string to float

Tags: python, string

I need to accept inputs in the form of 123.456,78.

```
num = float(input("enter your annual salary."))
thousands_separator = "."
fractional_separator = ","
num2 ="{:,.2f}".format(num)
print(num2)
```

> hi

> 50.000,00

> Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "main.py", line 1, in

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '50.000,00'

Comment: You cannot have a comma in a float

Comment: `num = float(input("annual salary: ").replace(".", "").replace(",", "."))`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert to float with a comma in the string. It only accepts a digit or a decimal point. So convert to a float after you edited it to the way python wants it.

This should help:

```
num = input("enter your annual salary.")
num = num.replace(".", "")
num = num.replace(",", ".")
num2 ="{:,.2f}".format(float(num))
print(num2)
```

Comment: @toyotaSupra you were supposed to enter value 123.456,78